# Why isn't Dirac credited with the discovery of the Aharonov-Bohm effect?

Tags: history, magnetic-monopoles, berry-pancharatnam-phase, dirac-monopole, dirac-string

Above equation (8) of Dirac's [famous 1931 paper](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/133/821/60) in which he proposes his quantization condition for magnetic monopoles, he says "the change in [an electron's] phase around [a] closed curve [is] $2 \pi n + e/\hbar c \int {\bf H} \cdot d{\bf S}$."  This sure sounds like the [Aharonov-Bohm effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect) to me.  And he clearly understood that the effect would still work if the magnetic field itself vanishes along the electron's path, because his entire magnetic charge quantization argument boils down to "magnetic monopoles can be thought of as endpoints of *infinitely thin* magnetic flux tubes, and electrons can't pick up a nontrivial phase as they circle around these flux tubes, even from far away."  So why does the Wikipedia article credit the discovery of the effect to Ehrenberg and Siday in 1949, and then to Aharonov and Bohm in 1959?

Comment: Perhaps because the AB effect is a (proposed) _experiment_?

Comment: a question for history.whodidwhat.S.E. ?

Answer (score 10):

Dirac's discovery of the quantization of the magnetic charge is distinct from the Aharonov-Bohm effect. 
These effects depend on different topological properties of the manifold on which a charged particle moves. 
The Aharonov-Bohm effect appears on manifolds with a nonvanishing first cohomology group $H^1(M)$, 
while the Dirac quantization condition takes place when the second cohomology group $H^2(M)$is nontrivial.
Please see, for example, V.P. Nair's [lecture note](http://www.itp.uni-hannover.de/~lechtenf/Events/20-geom-quant.pdf)s section 4 (pages 15-19).

In fact, these two effects combine to constitute all possible quantization types of a charged particle moving on a manifold.

It is true (in both cases) that when a charged particle moves on a trajectory $\Gamma$ on the manifold $M$, 
its wave function acquires a geometric phase of

$$ e^{\frac{ie}{\hbar c} \int_{\Gamma}\mathbf{A}. d\mathbf{r}}$$

However, the consequences are different. In the first case (Aharonov-Bohm), the vector potential is proportional
to a closed but nonexact one form $\alpha$ on the manifold.

$$ A = \frac{\Phi}{2\pi} \alpha$$

This is the famous vector potential of the Aharonov-Bohm effect whose  corresoponding magnetic field vanishes ($\Phi$ is the magnetic flux).

$$ B = dA = \frac{\Phi}{2\pi} d\alpha = 0$$

When the particle moves on a loop dual to this form in homology, i.e., a noncontractible loop, the result (by the Stokes theorm) will not depend on which loop we take as a representative:

$$\int_{\Gamma_1}\mathbf{A}. d\mathbf{r} - \int_{\Gamma_2}\mathbf{A}. d\mathbf{r} = \int_S \mathbf{B}.d\mathbf{S} = 0$$

where $S$ is the area enclosed by $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$.

Moreover, in the special case where $M=S^1$ (the circle), in which

$$\alpha = d\theta$$,

(The angle along the circumference).

In this case, the acquired phase is:

$$\frac{e \Phi}{\hbar c}$$

This means that two fluxes differing by $\frac{2 \pi\hbar c}{e}$ are physically equivalent.

In the second case when: $H^2(M)$is nontrivial, choosing the a closed trajectory to lie on a noncontractible two dimensional surface $\Omega$, 
allows us to compute the flux through the two halfs of the surface $\Omega_{\pm}$ whose boundaries is the closed trajectory:

$$\Phi_{\pm} = \int_{\Gamma} A_{\pm} = \pm \int_{\Omega_{\pm}} B$$.

Thus the phase difference acquired by the wave function when working using the upper half and the lower half coordinates is

$$ \frac{e}{\hbar c}(\int_{\Omega_{+}}B + \int_{\Omega_{-}} B) = \frac{e}{\hbar c} \int_{\Omega} B $$

In the case of a monopole

$$\int_{\Omega} B = 4 \pi g$$

(The magnetic charge).

The phase difference should be an integer multiple of $2 \pi$ since it is physically equivalent to work on the lower or the upper halves. Thus
we get the Dirac's quantization condition:

$$\frac{eg}{\hbar c} = \frac{n}{2}$$

Please observe also that in the present case the geometric phase is not topological since the magnetic field is nonvanishing.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "magnetic field is nonvanishing"? Even far away from the magnetic charge? It does not matter because the quantization is not due to presence of $g$!

Comment: @ Vladimir Kalitvianski I meant not identically zero as in the Aharonov-Bohm case

Comment: But in both cases the field $B$ outside solenoid is identically zero and in both cases it is not zero within the solenoid.

Comment: @ Vladimir Kalitvianski but $B$ in the monopole case is constant on the surface of the sphere and if you consider the whole 3-space it behaves according the inverse square law. Its flux throug a finite surface does not vanish.

Comment: But we do not consider the field $B(\mathbf{r})$ of the monopole! Dirac's quantization of $g$ is derived from scattering from a solenoid field.

Comment: Also, I think you mean that for a *contractible* loop the acquired Aharonov-Bohm phase is zero.

Comment: But more importantly, I think you're missing the point of my question.  I agree that the Aharonov-Bohm effect and Dirac monopole quantization are distinct phenomena and either one can be proven without reference to the other.  But my point is that *Dirac's original argument* for monopole quantization first derived the Aharonov-Bohm effect and then used it to prove monopole quantization.  Your argument involving cohomology is anachronistic, because Dirac didn't use any of those mathematical tools in his paper.

Comment: 1) The $\pi$ errors were corrected. 2) The expression written for the Aharonov-Bohm case is the difference between the 
geometric phases corresponding to two noncontractible loops $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ encircling each other, thus it is vanishing.

Comment: 3) Dirac's nodal line (Dirac string) argument is equivalent to the argument given for the quantization of the magnetic charge given in the answer. It is true that sometimes authors call the Berry phase around the Dirac string an Aharonov-Bohm phase but this is misleading since a phase can be called an Aharonov-Bohm phase only if the integration path
lies entirely in a region where the magnetic field is vanishing and this is not true in the case of the magnetic monopole.

Comment: 4)I'll post an update to this answer with a detailed explanation of the equivalence of the two arguments which again has a deep origin in the theory of cohomology.